# Why do I receive DEBUG=True error when trying to connect to server?

Tags: django

I use Django for a project. Originally I was having issues with building a functioning login page and it led to errors due to import login, so I changed it to `LoginView` so it can find login and that led to my next error.

I am trying to load my login html page, however I keep getting an error relating to `settings.py`. The error is related to having the setting `DEBUG=True` and potentially changing it to false.

I tried to change it to false but terminal refuses to connect and it shows that I must set settings.`ALLOWED_HOSTS` if DEBUG is False. I have no idea what this means: results online shows ip address etc.

## SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

```
DEBUG = True 

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

I expected no errors and also expected the server to start running so I can access login html document via the site.

Comment: Are you running this locally or on a remote server/host?

Comment: It's perfectly fine to run with DEBUG=True while you are testing with the developlemt server. You can also run with DEBUG=True and test with a "real" server (local  to your network and protected by your firewall). It's only at that point that you should worry about setting DEBUG=False and about what else you need to change.

Comment: That message is just a warning, you should have no problem with it. Please, share the whole traceback of the exception you are getting

Answer (score 1):

`ALLOWED_HOSTS` [setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) means that you have to write there your server's IP address, on which your application will be running and from which your application will accept the connections.
Also try to set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` but wildcard is not recommended on the prod.